# How to navigate from one ViewModel to another in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, caliburn.micro

I want to navigate from a login screen to the dashboard in my Silverlight OOB app.

I started using Caliburn.Micro but now I'm having doubts seeing as all I can use is the `Conductor`. Or am I missing something?

**Note**: I changed *constructor* to *`Conductor`* as originally intended. This is what you get for not proofreading your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you could display a login screen, probably the nicest is to initiate it from your `ShellViewModel`.  So, your `ShellViewModel` would have a dependency on your `LoginViewModel`, which you could inject as an abstraction (`ILoginViewModel`), or better still use an abstract factory instead, and inject that into your `ShellViewModel` constructor.

Either way, once you have an instance of your `LoginViewModel` in the `ShellViewModel`, you can display it either as a modal dialog box (in which case use the Caliburn.Micro `WindowManager.ShowDialog` method - inject this dependency as an `IWindowManager` abstraction), or display the login view as part of your shell views main content area, in which case your `ShellViewModel` would be a conductor, and will activate an instance of your `LoginViewModel` with the `ActivateItem` method.

Once you have received input from your `LoginViewModel`, either as a modal dialog or conducted view, you can display your `DashboardViewModel` as appropriate using the `ShellViewModel` as a conductor.

Comment: I am sorry but I only just now noticed I typed constructor instead of conductor. I am so sorry. I was on medication yesterday because of a soar throat and I haven't proofread the question. Still, you answer showed me a lot of how it's supposed to be done.